# IOS-Charts Adjust circle radius for individual line chart data point

Tags: swift, swift3, ios-charts

I'm using iOS-Charts linechart view to draw lines that have zero circle radius and I would like the user to be able to drop Points on the line. Is there a way to change an individual data points circle radius from zero to 20 by using the delegate chartValueSelected?

I can easily change the entire dataSet circleRadius, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do individual data points.

```
lineChartDataSet2.circleRadius = 0
lineChartDataSet2.circleRadius = 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this in an application by actually having multiple data sets, the second data set being used only for adding points on the same line but with a given circle radius. I checked with the developers of *Charts* and there's no other way to achieve it.

I have:

```
- (void)displayChartWithSet:(LineChartDataSet *)set highlightedSet:(LineChartDataSet *)highlightedSet {
set.drawValuesEnabled = NO;
    set.drawCirclesEnabled = YES;
    set.circleColors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[UIColor clearColor]];
    set.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    set.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    set.mode = LineChartModeHorizontalBezier;
    //Builds the data to be presented from two distinct data sets
    // one containing only points with a radius
    LineChartData *data = [[LineChartData alloc] initWithDataSets:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:set, highlightedSet, nil]];
}
```

This allows me to add individual points to the highlighted set and then redraw the view when needed, or have a `nil` set and have no highlighted points. There's a further setup function for the highlighted data set that does the configuration of points.